# How to play audio in notification action in ios8?

Tags: objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios8

I'm trying to use new ios8 notification actions to let users play audio from their lock screen.

I manage to download the data in the background, but the avaudioplayer does not seem to play.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Here is the code :

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString       *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
{
//handle the actions
if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"ACCEPT_IDENTIFIER"]){
    Message *newMessage = [Message rawMessageToInstance:[userInfo valueForKey:@"message"]];
    AVAudioSession* session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    BOOL success; NSError* error;
    success = [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
                             error:&error];
    if (!success)
        NSLog(@"AVAudioSession error setting category:%@",error);
    [session setActive:YES error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%lu",newMessage.identifier);
    [ApiUtils downloadAudioFileAtURL:[newMessage getMessageURL] success:^void(NSData *data) {

        AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:nil];
        [player setVolume:2];
        [player play];
        [self performSelector:@selector(completeNotif:) withObject:completionHandler afterDelay:[player duration]];
    } failure:^(){
        completionHandler();
    }];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem ... first I came up, it must have to do something with background and sound playing options - so I added the background audio flag to the info.plist.

With standard AVAudio stuf it works on the simulator, but not on the device. The special hook is, that you want to start the audio while you are in background - so add the code from anger: [How to use kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10180500/how-to-use-kaudiosessionproperty-overridecategorymixwithothers) before starting with the AVAudioPlayer and it will also work on the device.

Hope that helps, for me it works.